# Writing and reading variables in a file in Python

Tags: python, file, variables, python-2.x

How do I make my code create a file where it store variables and then later read the variables from the file so they are usable in my code.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use the pickle module to accomplish this.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example)

```
import pickle
```

Here's some sample data:

```
key_value_mapping = dict(tuple=(), string='', list=[], int=0, set=set())
```

Provide a path that you want the file to exist at, e.g.:

```
file_location= '/temp/foobar'
```

We need to open a file to write (w) as a binary (b) file (see the `'wb'` flags being passed to the open function). These two lines demonstrate how to do this:

```
with open(file_location, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(key_value_mapping, file)
```

Finally, we need to open the file to read (r) it as a binary (b) file, and retrieve the data:

```
with open(file_location, 'rb') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)
    print(data)

{'tuple': (), 'set': set(), 'int': 0, 'list': [], 'string': ''}
```